# IE 7 not shows the data on jsp page

Tags: html, jsp, internet-explorer-7, jstl

I have list of the objects.that i am display using the jstl (for:each tag),the tag is generates the data but it not shown on the jsp page.I checked the same thing for the IE8 and Firefox browser and it working properly.

```
 <c:forEach items="${userList}" var="user">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left">
          <tbody>                                           
              <tr><td><c:out value="${user.name}"/></td></tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
 </c:forEach>
```

another important point is that when i view the page source it shows me all the data in the above format,i.e my data is render on the page but not showing on the browser.

Please help me ..

Comment: Most likely HTML and/or CSS related. Paste your HTML source at jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Basically when i execute the above code it prints the data for the very first user.After that it not showing any data on the screen.but in the page source all the data is visible.

Comment: Browsers does not retrieve Java/JSP code. Posting Java/JSP code is therefore completely irrelevant. You need to extract the generated HTML code from *View Source*, save it in the file and cut it as much as possible down as long as it reproduces the problem and then post it here. By the way, how many users are there? Not over 1000 I hope?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way;

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left">
  <tbody>
   <c:forEach items="${userList}" var="user">
     <tr>
      <td><c:out value="${user.name}"/></td>
     </tr>
   </c:forEach>
 </tbody>
</table>
```